# why ajax call send me error but this same code work well in other server

Tags: php, ajax

I have a problem whith ajax call, have the excactly same code in other url and works fine, but in this is not work, and send me this error in console.

this is my call

```
$(document).on('click', '.enviarcorreo', function() {


    nombre = $('#name').val();
    telefono = $('#phone').val();
    correo = $('#email').val();
    mensaje = $('#coments').val();
    // alert($('#name').val());

    i = 0;
    // $(".cat1").css( 'background-color', 'blue' );
    // $('.desc1').css('display','none')
    $.ajax({
        url: 'template/correo.php', //ruta de tu archivo php en el cual se hace la consulta y se obtendra el resultado 
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html', //dataType: xml, json, script, o html
        data: {
            nombre: nombre,
            telefono: telefono,
            correo: correo,
            mensaje: mensaje
        }, //se evia el valor seleccionado en tu select
        success: function(result) {
            $("#correo").html(result); //si la peticion se realizo sin errores te regresara un valor y lo insetas en tu table html
            alert("si funciona");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

and this is the error in console

```
POST https://gamamateriales.com/template/correo.php 500

{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and remove all of the extra code.  We only need to see the code segment that is causing the error.  It's your job to debug this, not ours.  We assist with resolving the problem, not with debugging.  Also, please include the text of the error in your question, not an image of it.

Comment: So look at the error log on the server. We can not guess what the php is complaining about with a 500 error.

Comment: I think this error is coming from the server side (500), check your server code

Comment: dont know why, in local the ajax call works perfectly, but in server not

Comment: have you tried to hard reload?